# How can I access the correct XPI from a Firefox fork?

Tags: linux, firefox, desktop, firefox-extensions, gnu

I am running a Firefox fork on GNU/Linux that [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) does not recognise. So instead of giving me XPI links it gives me buttons to "Get Firefox Now!".

Digging into the HTML source I can find links to XPI files ending `an-fx.xpi` but downloading these and picking the install-from-file route doesn't seem to work. (The plugin installs but doesn't work.) I'm thinking maybe they're for Firefox for Android?

How can I make sure I'm accessing XPIs for the GNU/Linux desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to change the
[User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
string that identifies
your browser to one that the store will accept as bona-fide Firefox.

To override this string :

1. Type about:config into Firefox’s address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Type `general.useragent.overridepreference` in the search box,
   and if it exists go to step 4 (double-click it)
3. Right-click on the `about:config` page, point to `New`, and select `String`
4. Name the preference `general.useragent.override`
5. Enter your desired user agent as the value of the preference.

A searchable database of user-agent strings can be found in
[myip.ms](https://myip.ms/browse/comp_browseragents/Computer_Browser_Agents.html),
where you can search for one that suits you.

Another (tiring) solution would be to google for the addon and then download
the xpi file.